# Optimal Online Search Problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I want to find an optimal stopping rule for the game described below:

**Setting**:

Let's say I have a discrete time-series $\bf {P_t}$, where $t\in \{0, 1,2,\dots, N\}$,

and $\bf P_0 = 0$,

$\bf P_{i+1} = \begin{cases}
  \bf P_{i} +1 & \text{with prob.} & \alpha_i \\    
  \bf P_{i} -1 & \text{with prob.} & 1- \alpha_i
\end{cases}$

Note that $\alpha_i$ is only known at time $i$ and not before it. In addition, we know the Probability Mass Function of $\bf P_K$ $\forall k \in \{1,2,\dots N\}$ at time $0$.

**Rule**:

At any given time $\tau$, I can decide to take $P_\tau$ or continue the game. If at time $N$ I have not taken a value, $P_N$ is automatically given to me.

**Goal**:

Choose an optimal stopping rule to maximize the game's expected value.

**Edit**:

My rudimentary attempt has been to choose $\tau$ based on the value that maximizes $P_k$.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to solve the problem.